# Viber not starting on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, qt5, transparency, viber

After installing viber (version 13.3.1) from official debian [package](https://www.viber.com/en/download/) viber won't start normally.

Viber is installed using dpkg command:

```
$ dpkg -i viber.deb
```

When viber is started, main window is not showing, instead it shows transparent window as shown below:

[image: viber window transparent]

I've found solution and wanted to share in case someone else bumps into this.

Comment: FYI: Xubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: Thanks for the info, thought that Ubuntu flavors are supported for 5 years also. I am using Linux Mint Xfce 18.3 as my daily driver but definitely good to know.

Comment: No, only 'main' packages have security updates for 5 years, not *flavors* (eg. if you read Xubuntu's site https://xubuntu.org/release/16-04/ it reports EOL April-2019). It's always been this way, the 'main' repository only was extended for five years (Ubuntu thus doesn't have 'universe' or non-5 year packages included or enabled on install). Mint has a lower security model than Ubuntu does... they sort of have to given their use of run-time *adjustments* to tweak foreign (Ubuntu) packages.  For the 16.04 cycle Ubuntu Kylin 16.04 was given 5 years of life (once-off).  Always check release notes

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings though & helping any remaining Xubuntu 16.04 users (there will still be some..).

Comment: Thank you for helpful comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viber is using Qt5 framework.

One of the Qt plugins is causing issues with the viber application: namely
**libqxcb-glx-integration.so**

We should replace this library with the library provided with our distribution as shown below:

```bsh
$ cd /opt/viber/plugins/xcbglintegrations/
$ mv libqxcb-glx-integration.so libqxcb-glx-integration_bkp.so
$ ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so
```

Now viber should work normally.

This solution can also be helpful for other Qt applications.
Same fix can be applied for the [zoom](https://zoom.us/support/download) application (tested).

Tested on:
*Xubuntu 16.04*
*Linux Mint Xfce 18.3*